# Get next sequence number

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a class `Account` with a property `number` which has as value fe:

```
130.11.0000001

[plan_code].[year].[sequential number]
```

Now I have this `number` property mapped as a `String`.
So when I want to create a second `Account` for the same `Plan (code=130)` it should get `number = 130.11.0000002`.

When an `Account` for `plan(code=100)` is made it should have `number=100.11.0000001`

I was thinking of using `hilo` generator from hibernate, but have no idea how to start and if this is even possible using `hilo generator`. So any pointers/ideas of implementation are welcome!

Maybe I should start making `number` property of type `AccountNumber` with as id a hilo generated value?

Comment: Do you have a database and are you already using Hibernate or are you just trying to use a Hibernate class to generate a unique id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a class that implements account number as three fields and it's `toString` produces the combination? Then doing the increment is easy given the previous instance.

```
public class AccountNumber{
     public final int planCode;
     public final int year;
     public final int sequenceNumber;

     ...

     public static AccountNumber getNextSequenceNumber(AccountNumber previous)...
}
```

Comment: but the sequenceNumber isn't unique, only the combination of plancode+year+sequencenumber is unique, so when an Account for plan(code=100) is made it should have number=100.11.0000001

Comment: Will you always have the most recent element for an plancode + year when you attempt to create the next one? If so, pass in that object, use it's plancode + year and increment the sequence number. If not, create a `Multimap<Integer, Multimap<Integer, Integer>>` where first key is planCode, second key is year.

Comment: Or better yet `Table<Integer, Integer, TreeSet<Integer>>`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120414/how-can-i-use-generated-value-within-composite-keys)

You need to set the planCode and year by hand and let hibernate generate the sequenceNumber using a built in generator.

I have not tested though