# Composite ID Hibernate with GeneratedValue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have been trying to persist an object which has a Composite ID.

```
TABLEUSER
ID - auto_increment
name


TABLEUSER2
userid (foreing key from tableUSER)
keynum2
```

I have tried lareadt with the @EmbeddedId annotation.  The problem is that I'm trying to get the foreign key as follows

```
@GeneratedValue(generator = "foreign")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "foreign",
        strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = {@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "property", value = "user")})
```

This would work perfect if it was a single key in TABLE USER, but as it's a composite ID I cannot set it.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use generated value within composite keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120414/how-can-i-use-generated-value-within-composite-keys)

Comment: In fact! i read that post before, and didnt get to any conclusion.
Now i have done something different but related the link, without using EmbbededID at all and it works. the difference is that i keep using GenericGenerator as i did before instance of TableGenerator

Comment: the link was, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1150